# How can I delay something in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to set a delay on this script but I don't know how it works. So I would like to ask if someone can help me with a Solution for this/

```
const el = document.getElementById("search-label");
el.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    
    if(event.key === "Enter") {
      el.blur();
  }

});
```

Comment: You put setTimeout in your title. Why didn't you actually use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const el = document.getElementById("search-label");
el.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.key === "Enter") {
        setTimeout(function(){  
             el.blur();
        }, 5000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for delay you can use settimeout function

**Example:**

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
  console.log("Hello stackoverflow"); // Runs after 5 seconds
}, 5000); // five second
```